# Find offset sequence in an array of integers

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I have numerous arrays with between 500 and 1000 integers.  I want to find any instances of a part of a certain sequence pattern in these arrays.  For instance, I have a offset pattern

```
offset = [-15, -12, -5, -1, 1, 10, 20, 32]
```

and a sorted list of positive integers

```
A = [2, 8, 12, 15, 22, ...] # Length ~ 1000
```

and I want to find all such integers N such that for each `a` in `offset`, `N + a` is an element of `A`.

**However**, I would ideally be able to set a threshold for the number of values of `a` needed to make `N` a match.  So, if my offset is 3, perhaps only `N - 12`, `N - 1`, and `N + 20` are values that exist in `A` and I want to keep `N`.

I can easily write a brute force algorithm to go through and test this condition - but with thousands of such arrays to test against several pattens, I wonder if there might be a better approach for this.  Thanks.

---

As requested, here's some pseudocode for a brute force algorithm:

```
# Not perfect because it doesn't take into account possible boundary cutoffs
for a in A:
    new_offset = [x + a for x in offset]
    count = sum(x in A for x in new_offset)

    if count >= threshhold:
        # keep a, and work out N
```

Comment: It might help clarify precisely what you want if you at least *show* us what that brute force algorithm would be.

Comment: Could absolutely use list comprehension to do this.

Comment: @wnnmaw: For at least *some* of `a`s in `offset`, `N+a` is in `A`.  I need a changeable threshold for the number of offset values that need to match.   @mhlester, I'll write up some pseudocode

Comment: @user2852809, yeah, I noticed that when I re-read your post

Comment: What is a typical length of offset, and what range of integers do you expect to see (i.e. are all the integers in the array less than 10,000 for example)?  (For long offsets and small ranges you may be better off using the Fast Fourier Transform)

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz, the `offset` array is much shorter than `A`.  `A` can extend to very large numbers - forgot to include that.  I'll look into fft, but don't know how useful it'll be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
offsets = [-15, -12, -5, -1, 1, 10, 20, 32]
A = {2, 8, 12, 15, 22, ...} # a set of length ~ 1000
N = range(min(A)+min(offsets),max(A)+max(offsets)+1)
THRESHOLD = 3

NN = [num for num in N if sum((1 for offset in offsets if num+offset in A)) >= THRESHOLD]
```

Alternatively, shortcircuit once you've passed `THRESHOLD`

```
offsets = [-15, -12, -5, -1, 1, 10, 20, 32]
A = {2, 8, 12, 15, 22, ...} # a set of length ~ 1000
test_range = range(min(A)+min(offsets),max(A)+max(offsets)+1)
THRESHOLD = 3

N = set()
for value in test_range:
    count = 0
    for offset in offsets:
        if value+offset in A: count += 1
        else: continue
        if count == 3:
            N.add(value)
            break
```

Comment: But what if max(A) is a very large number?  This would be very inefficient, if I follow it correctly.

Comment: Probably more efficient to make A a set instead of a list?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz Thanks, good thought! My usual mental checklist for those optimizations goes: "Well did he give it to me as a set? No. Does he explicitly state they're unique values? No." But since we don't care about the order or A nor do duplicate values get tested (with any different results anyway), it doesn't matter!

Comment: So I just tested this with with a list of 1000 random numbers between 0 and 9,999, and it didn't take too long, maybe about half a second at most.  One note though, you'll wanna make those capitals A's on your third line

Comment: @wnnmaw thanks. Been having a lot of silly syntax issues today.

Comment: You should fix `A[0]`, `A[-1]` as well, indexing is not possible with sets. :)

Comment: @wnnmaw, But what if A ranges from 1 to 1,000,000?  It just seems like this approach would be too slow.

Comment: @user2852809 then you'll want to use a `for` loop and shortcircuit it when you've found `THRESHOLD` entries. I'll edit....

Comment: @user2852809, running the list comprehension with with a list of 1000 random numbers ranging from 0, 1,000,000 took 122 seconds

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly. It seems to me that if len(offset) << len(A), for each value in offset, you could calculate A-offset, then count the number rows each value occurs in. If the value occurs at least x times, where x is your minimum cutoff, then that value meets your critereon.

For example if your values are:
offset = [-3,-1,1]
A = [1, 3, 5, 7]

You would calculate
[4, 6, 8, 10]
[2, 4, 6, 8]
[0, 2, 4, 6]

Then you'd count:
0: 1
2: 2
4: 3
6: 3
8: 2
10: 1

So 4 and 6 should work for N.

The complexity of this would be O(len(offset) * len(A))

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a similar algorithm to the above, but not sure.

```
from collections import Counter
counters = Counter()

# Python 2.6: 
# from collections import defaultdict
# counters = defaultdict(int)

from itertools import product
Aset = set(A)
for aval, offset in product(A, offset):
    counters[aval-offset] += 1

# 3 is the threshold here; change at will.
[key for key, val in counters.items() if val > 3]
```

Appears to work. What we are doing: If there is a number N such that N+offset is in A, then we can go to that value in A, and Aval-offset = N. Small, dumb example:

```
A = [1,3,5,10]
offset = [-2, 5]
```

There is a number, 5, that meets this criteria. However, we don't know it yet. That number is 3 + 2, and 10-5. We'll go through the first time for -2, and get [3, 5, 7, 12] by adding 2 back to every A. Then, we'll go through again for 5, and get [-4, -2, 0, 5] by subtracting 5 from every A. This gives us counters like this:

```
-4: 1
-2: 1
 0: 1
 3: 1
 5: 2
 7: 1
12: 1
```

5 is the only one that matched for two entries.

On the offsets given and a randomly-generated sequence of ~1000 random integers between 0 and 4000 (actual min/max 6/3999, and 1200 numbers were generated, put through list(set()) to remove duplicates, then sorted), creating the dictionary took ~2.5 mS. If it matters, for this algorithm, you don't really need to sort A, but removing duplicates is necessary (unless you really want it to count twice).